# В WinForm при прорисовке второй линии добавляется лишняя линия

Tags: windows, winforms, c++-cli

При прорисовке кривой добавляется лишняя линия которой быть по идее не должно[image: прямая из начала координат в конец не должна тут быть]

Функция, которая прорисовывает график:

```
double begin = this->begin->Text == "" ? 0 : Convert::ToDouble(this->begin->Text);
this->begin->Text = Convert::ToString(begin);
double end = this->end->Text == "" ? 10 : Convert::ToDouble(this->end->Text);
if (end - begin < 15) {
    end += 15;
}
this->end->Text = Convert::ToString(end);
double h = this->H->Text == "" ? 0.01 : Convert::ToDouble(this->H->Text);
this->H->Text = Convert::ToString(h);
double lambda = this->lambda->Text == "" ? 3 : Convert::ToDouble(this->lambda->Text);
this->lambda->Text = Convert::ToString(lambda);
double x0dash = this->_xdash0->Text == "" ? 1 : Convert::ToDouble(this->_xdash0->Text);
this->_xdash0->Text = Convert::ToString(x0dash);

std::vector<double> res;
runge_kutta(begin, end, h, lambda, x0dash, res);
int count = 0;
this->prev_dv->Text = Convert::ToString(res[res.size() - 1]);
res.pop_back();
this->prev_dx->Text = Convert::ToString(res[res.size() - 1]);
for (float i = begin + 1; i < end; i+=h) {
    this->chart1->Series["Series1"]->Points->AddXY(i,res[count]);
    ++count;
}
```